# In Highchart in R how to change colors by negative and positive values in a bar chart

Tags: javascript, r, highcharts

This is my dataframe:

```
    df <- structure(list(month_date = structure(c(13149, 13180, 13208, 
13239, 13269, 13300, 13330, 13361, 13392, 13422, 13453, 13483
), class = "Date"), monthly_error = c(-228, -445, -1213, -1937, 
-687, -1437, -1275, -293, -524, 242, -100, -359), pos_neg = c("negative", 
"negative", "negative", "negative", "negative", "negative", "negative", 
"negative", "negative", "positive", "negative", "negative")), row.names = c(NA, 
-12L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I want to change the color to "red" to negative values and "blue" to positive values.

```
highchart() %>% 
  
  hc_add_series(data = df ,"column",
                color = colors[1],
                hcaes(x = month_date, y = monthly_error, color = pos_neg),
                showInLegend = TRUE)
```

How can I set this?

In ggplot we can set this manually.

But how can I do this in Highchart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adapting the answer on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42443906/how-to-change-the-palette-colors-of-a-highcharter-column-plot-which-depends-on-a) to your case you could add a column of hex colors to your data which could then be mapped on the `color` aes, where I use `htmltools:: parseCssColors` to convert R color names to hex code:

```r
library(highcharter)

df$color <- ifelse(df$pos_neg == "negative", "red", "blue")
df$color <- htmltools::parseCssColors(df$color)

highchart() %>% 
  hc_add_series(data = df, "column",
                hcaes(x = month_date, y = monthly_error, color = color),
                showInLegend = TRUE)
```

[image]