# NegativeColors in Highcharts with R

Tags: r, highcharts, r-highcharter

I'm trying to plot a graph with two colors according if it is positive or negative values, using highchart in R. I simplify a code in the next way:

```
x <- c(-3, -4, 1, 4, 8)


dt <- seq(as.Date("2018-01-01"), as.Date("2018-01-05"), by = "days")

ts <- xts(x, dt )
names(ts)="serie"
print(ts)

highchart(type="stock") %>%
  hc_add_series(ts$"serie",
                type = "lollipop",
                color="black")
```

I'm trying to plot the graph with black color for positive values and green color for negative ones. I checked that we can use negativeColor in JS, ¿is there a way to use this on R? For example in JS: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/9ay8vezd/

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73354888/in-highchart-in-r-how-to-change-colors-by-negative-and-positive-values-in-a-bar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply add `negativeColor = 'green'` as an argument to `hc_add_series`:

```
library(highcharter)

x <- c(-3, -4, 1, 4, 8)

dt <- seq(as.Date("2018-01-01"), as.Date("2018-01-05"), by = "days")

ts <- xts::xts(x, dt )
names(ts)="serie"

highchart(type="stock") %>%
  hc_add_series(ts$"serie",
                type = "lollipop",
                color =  'black',
                negativeColor = 'green')
```

[image]